# Custom grouping of d3 data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, grouping

I have the following json:

```
[{"Time":"2017-02-07 16:14:06"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 16:58:49"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 17:07:11"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 18:13:19"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 13:56:06"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 19:07:57"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 12:08:58"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 01:41:00"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 11:56:49"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 02:45:29"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 11:40:07"},
{"Time":"2017-02-07 04:15:45"},
]
```

I am parsing these dates inside of a d3.json function to get 24 hour values like so:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

d3.json("/wp-content/themes/jordan/js/data.json", function(d){

    d.forEach(function(d){
        d.Time = parseDate(d.Time).getHours();
        console.log(d.Time);
    });
});
```

This is returning all of my values as an integer on a 24-hour scale.  All is good.  How can I use `d3.nest()` to group all of my hour values into 4 hour increments?  Ex. 0 - 4, 4 - 8, 8 - 12, 12 - 16, 16 - 20, 20 - 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define periods array this way

```
var periods = ['0 - 4', '4 - 8', '8 - 12', '12 - 16', '16 - 20', '20 - 24']
```

Then you can easily define which period a particual hour belongs to this way

```
period[Math.floor(d/4)]
```

Full code

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse,
    periods = ['0 - 4', '4 - 8', '8 - 12', '12 - 16', '16 - 20', '20 - 24'];

d3.json("/wp-content/themes/jordan/js/data.json", function(data) {
    data = data.map(function(d) {
        return parseDate(d.Time).getHours();
    });

    data = d3.nest()
             .key(function(d) {
                 return periods[Math.floor(d/4)];
             })
             .entries(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton...any insight as to how I can then use those ranges to create a bar chart.  Each range will be a bar chart with height based on the number of entries in each range.

Comment: nah, haven't worked with d3 much to come up with the solution without looking in the docs but I'm sure you can do it yourself as it's a simple thing to do :)